# Smallest Sigma Field in a Certain Set

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I found different pages about sigma algebra but I did not understand very well because they have poor and non-understandable examples.
For example, what is the smallest sigma field in the set $B$ where $B = \{1,2,3,4\}$.
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest sigma-field over any non-empty set $B$ is $\{ \emptyset, B\}$. This is sometimes called the *trivial* sigma-field.